# How can I go back to a previous commit deleting everything I've posted in both local/public repos?

Tags: git, visual-studio-2017, commit, ignore

I was in local repo. Stage + Commit, than Push to the server. Master Commit now is `4e4f27c554ee42e5fb7a0b62b6d921cbd05819c9`.

I have made a mistake! Doh...

I'd like to return to the previous commit, returning to `5e814650f03d04e56fcb069000f77123c1b5273b`, in **both** public e local repo.

How can I do it? Tried `git push origin +5e814650f03d04e56fcb069000f77123c1b5273b:master`, but on local repo I can still see the wrong Commit in Outgoing Commits window (Visual Studio Git Tool), and I don't know how to remove it.

What's the best way?

Answer (score 4):

You can either use `git revert` or `git reset` as per your needs:-

- Use `git revert <commit_ID>` - The reverted commit is not deleted. Rather, Git creates a new commit with the included files reverted to their previous state.
  So your version control history moves forward while the state of your files moves backwards.
- Use `git reset --hard <commit_ID>` -  Git discards any commits between the current state of the repo and the target commit. The branch will then appear to stop at the commit you reset the HEAD to. Although the commits no longer appear to be a part of your branch history, they are not deleted. They are still stored in Git.

After that, push your changes to remote (Assuming that your branch is called master both here and remotely, and that your remote is called origin):-

```
# note this will hard reset your commit
git reset --hard <commit-hash>
# pushing changes to remote
git push -f origin master
```

Comment: Uhm, what if I have edits (not staged yet)? That --hard will remove all of them also. Can I avoid it?

Comment: @markzzz: staged or not, `git reset --hard` will destroy them, yes. The solution is to commit them. Of course this gets tricky because the commit goes on the current branch. The solution to *that* problem is sometimes `git stash`, which makes commits that are on *no* branch, and lets you recover the stashed changes later, after resetting the current branch or moving to a different one. (I'm not a big fan of `git stash` but this particular use case is a decent one.)

Comment: I see, thanks! Also: "Although the commits no longer appear to be a part of your branch history, they are not deleted.". What if I'd like to delete them totally? Any other futher command?